# Object orbiting a moving object in 2D

Tags: matlab, 2d, physics-engine

I am working on a system in which I have small moving objects in 2D and if 2 objects are close to each other, one starts to orbit the other. I am limited to those information:

I know the angle between the object that is not orbiting and the object orbiting at each time step
I know the distance between the centers of the 2 objects at each time step
The orbiting object can move at a maximum speed of d_max/t_step < max_radius/t_step
Max_radius is the maximum distance between 2 objects in which they can interact. If the distance is > max_radius the 2 objects don't attract anymore.

What I have right now is a formula like this:

```
fxy = e^(-alpha*d^2);
dx = 2*alpha*fxy*(sin(theta)*d);
dy = -2*alpha*fxy*(cos(theta)*d);
```

If i sum dx and dy to the coordinates of my orbiting obejct it will orbit around the other, but only if that remains still. How can I extend it so that the object keeps orbiting even if the other moves (obviously with the constraints I talked about above)?

Answer (score 0):

Add to dx and dy the delta-x and delta-y of the object it is orbiting.

Comment: So I will have:
PosX = PosX + dx + sin(theta)*d;
correct?

Comment: That is essentially correct, but you left out the alpha and fxy from your original formula.  Those are what determine the orbital velocity.

Comment: I already do that in the formula cause I add the dx and dy to the object but it only orbits if the other object is not moving. As soon as it starts moving the other object escapes. Do I need to adjust the alpha value? Is there a way to make it adapt the speed of the central object?

Comment: I see that depending on the alpha the dx and dy start going down to 0 quicker and the object stops...

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying.  The "central object" is not described by the equations above.  If you want to move with the central object, then you make that the reference position of your orbiting object.  You do that by doing what I state in the answer.

Comment: theta is the relative angle between the orbiting object and the central object and d is the distance.

Comment: But somehow the vector position of the central object must be known.  Changes in that vector in each frame of the simulation must be added to the vector position of the orbiting object.